# Open CSS sub menus in the opposite direction, when there is no horizontal space relative to the browser window available

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a CSS menu that loos like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xgjhk0kw/12/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a:only-child").addClass("only-child");
});
```

```css
#main_nav {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    background: #888;
    z-index: 300 !important;
}

#main_nav ul {
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background: #888;
    z-index: 300 !important;
    min-width: 150px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#main_nav a:hover {
    color: #FFFAF0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-1px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-1px);
    transform: translateY(-1px);
}

#main_nav ul a {
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:32px;
    padding:3px 15px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

#main_nav ul li {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#main_nav ul li.current-menu-item {
    background:#ddd;
}

#main_nav ul li:hover {
    background: #777;
}

#main_nav ul ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    background:#888;
    padding:0;
}

#main_nav ul ul li {
    float:none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}

#main_nav ul ul a {
    line-height:120%;
    padding:10px 15px;
}

#main_nav ul ul ul {
    top:0;
    left:100%;
}

#main_nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}

#main_nav > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 -3px 0 0;
}

.menu li:last-of-type { border-right: none; }
.menu li > a:after {position: absolute; right: 5px; content: '\25BA'; }
.menu > li > a:after {position: absolute; right: 0px; content: '\25BC'; }
.menu li > a.only-child:after { margin-left: 0; content: ''; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main_nav">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>

                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 1</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 3</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 5</a>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 7</a>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 9</a>
                                                            <ul>
                                                                <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 11</a>
                                                                    <ul>
                                                                        <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 13</a>
                                                                            <ul>
                                                                                <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
                                                                                <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
                                                                                <li><a href="#">Category 3</a></li>
                                                                                <li><a href="#">Category 4</a></li>
                                                                                <li><a href="#">Category 5</a></li>
                                                                            </ul>
                                                                        </li>
                                                                        <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 14</a></li>
                                                                    </ul>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 12</a></li>
                                                            </ul>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 10</a></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 8</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 6</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In one of the sub menus, many sub menus are opened one after the other causing a horizontal overflow, when there is no enough room to accommodate a sub menu after many sub menus are opened sequentially.

Is it possible to open a sub menu in the opposite direction, when there is no enough horizontal space relative to the browser window left to accommodate the last sub menu opened using whatever can make it possible - pure CSS, JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: It's possible using javascript/jquery to check if the submenu would not fit on the current screensize, but it's also a design issue you should consider first - in case the submenu would open in the opposite direction it'd look really weird (covering the previous submenu).

Comment: The sub menu that does not fit the browser window should cover the immediate previous sub menu.

Comment: Maybe it sounds a bit like too much, but would you consider a solution like this: in case the sub menu that would be displayed next would not fit in the screen, the active sub menus slide mid-tempo to the left ("under" sub menu level 1 which stays in place) and the critical sub menu is then displayed on the previous sub menu's position? Don't know if it's described clear enough but overlapping sub menus are somehow evil from user experience view.

Comment: I will accept any solution that just does not allow the sub menu (that does not fit the window) to span horizontally beyond the browser window.

Comment: I currently don't do ASP.NET anymore but about two years ago in Visual Studio 2010, there was a menu control in which a sub menu, if does not fit horizontally was overlapped to its immediate previous sub menu using some JavaScript/jQuery techniques.

Comment: Think I found it: http://www.telerik.com/forums/overlapping-menus  even with a linked image, but it looks like it was considered a bug. But for detection if element would be offscreen check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866293/how-to-find-out-if-a-element-overflows-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I get your problem but if you float the sub menu's left it will over overlap the previous sub menu. have you tried. try to do this:

```
#main_nav ul ul ul ....
```

until you are at the ul that need to be float left and than add float left. that is the only thing i know. What you also can do is that you let **menu1** *collapse vertical* (the sub menu's to).

You can also make that lage menu collapse vertical instead of horizontal

Comment: But based on what condition the sub menu is to be floated to left?

Answer (score 0):

Using media query you'll achieve the desired result: if the width of the viewport is equal or more than 500px the menu will float to the right otherwise will float to te left. You can adapt the width to your needs

```css
.menu {
    display: flex;
  }

  .menu li {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
        background-color: yellow;
  }

  .menu li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
  }

  .sub-menu li {
        background-color: red;
  }

  .menu ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    min-width: 150px;
        background-color: red;
    right: 0;
  }

  @media (min-width: 500px) {
    .menu ul {
      left: 0;
    }
  }

  .menu a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Menu item 1</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Submenu item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Submenu item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Submenu item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu item 2</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Submenu item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Submenu item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Submenu item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```