# how to determin if a ng-grid cell is using ellipsis

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

In the ng-grid css file there is a CSS element that is show below

```
.ngCellText {
  padding: 5px;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Basically when the cell text content goes over a limit it puts an ellipsis. How can you determine in your code when certain cell is using the ellipsis and act on that.?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6866314/516690

Comment: How is your suggestion even related to my question. Thanks but my question is about ng-grid and using ellipsis.

Comment: Maybe on the surface it's about ng-grid and using elipsis. What it's really about is figuring out when the css rule for text-overflow is applied to an element. (I.e. when the width of the text is too wide for the container.)

Comment: Appreciate it but would love to know the exact answer